# $\lim_{ n \to +\infty} \frac{ \prod_{ j=0 }^{ n-1 } \left( d-j \right) }{ n! }~$ nominator of product form and denominator of factorial

Tags: limits

The below lim should take zero I think.

$$  \lim_{ n \to +\infty} \frac{  \prod_{ j=0 }^{ n-1 } \left( d-j \right)   }{ n!   }  ~~ \leftarrow~~ d \in\mathbb{R}     $$

As $~ d \geq0 ~$ is held , I can find out the lim of above takes a zero since , the numerator $~ \prod_{ j=0 }^{ n-1 } \left( d-j \right) ~$ takes zero . Because , the only $~ \exists~~  j \ni j=d ~$ is held.

The problem is as $~ d <0 ~$  is held.

$$  d':= \left| d \right|  $$

$$  d=-d' $$

$$  \lim_{ n \to +\infty} \frac{  \prod_{ j=0 }^{ n-1 } \left( d-j \right)   }{ n!   }   $$

$$ = \lim_{ n \to +\infty} \frac{  \prod_{ j=0 }^{ n-1 } \left( -d'-j \right)   }{ n!   }   $$

$$ = \lim_{ n \to +\infty} \frac{  \prod_{ j=0 }^{ n-1 } \left( \left( -1 \right) \left( d'+j \right)  \right)   }{ n!   }   $$

$$ = \lim_{ n \to +\infty} \frac{  \left( -1 \right)^{n}\prod_{ j=0 }^{ n-1 }  \left( d'+j   \right)    }{ n!   }  ~~ \leftarrow~~ \text{Unable that } \left( d'+j   \right)~ \text{takes zero !}  $$

I thought that can I use l'hopital theorem however I think it is unable to calculate 1st order of derivative of $~ n! ~$

What can I do for next?

For instance imagine that we set $~ d'= 10^{ 4 }  ~$

$$ \lim_{ n \to +\infty} \frac{  \left( -1 \right)^{n}\prod_{ j=0 }^{ n-1 }  \left( d'+j   \right)    }{ n!   }    $$

$$ =\lim_{ n \to +\infty} \frac{  \left( -1 \right)^{n}\prod_{ j=0 }^{ n-1 }  \left( 10^{4}+j   \right)    }{ n!   }    $$

$$ =\lim_{ n \to +\infty} \frac{  \left( -1 \right)^{n}\left\{ \left( 10^{ 4 } +0 \right)\left( 10^{ 4 }+1 \right) \left( 10^{ 4 }+2 \right)\cdot\cdot\cdot \left( 10^{4} + \left( n-1 \right) \right)   \right\}     }{ n!   }    $$

I've been stucked from here...

Comment: You can rewrite the product in terms of Pochhammer symbol and maybe try plugging in large values for patterns. Maybe the limit is  $\pm$ 1?

Comment: Your work seems to tacitly assume that $d$ is an integer, when your claim in the beginning is with $d\in\Bbb R$, no? Also, the limit doesn't necessarily exist, it is the same as $\lim_{n\to\infty}\prod_{j=0}^{n-1}\left(\frac{d+1}{j+1}-1\right)$ eg., for $d=-2$, the expression is $(-1-1)(-\frac 12-1)(-\frac 13-1)\cdots=(-2)\cdot\dfrac{(-3)}2\cdot\dfrac{(-4)}3\cdots\leadsto\mathrm{DNE}$; alternating and approaching $n$ in absolute value.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* The limit does not exist for all $d<0$. Letting $d=-1$ we obtain
\begin{align*}
\lim_{ n \to +\infty} \frac{  \prod_{ j=0 }^{ n-1 } \left( (-1)-j \right)   }{ n!   }
&=\lim_{n\to +\infty}(-1)^n\frac{\prod_{j=0}^{n-1}(j+1)}{n!}\\
&=\lim_{n\to +\infty}(-1)^n\frac{n!}{n!}\\
&=\lim_{n\to +\infty}(-1)^n \ \to\   \not\exists
\end{align*}